# React object property has value but shows undefined on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a React app that get's it's data via API calls.

I have an array of objects that gets populated, but for some reason only 1 attribute in the objects is inaccessible only when the page is refreshed.

My account is new so unfortunately I cannot post pictures yet.

[Code Populating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtV6f.png)

When I log the object I can see the property, "price", has a value. However, when I try to access it, it shows undefined.

[Console.log code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buqd9.png)

[Browser Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6O0p.png)

Does anyone happen to know why this might be happening?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: @Vince this is not a good solution, you call your service to get price data in side for loop is a big no-no. Because, if you have 100+ objects in your array it might call 100 times, I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: +1 to @Mad's comment. Firestore doesn't really handle relational queries like that. You're better off de-normalising your data

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, my firestore data comes from the Stripe webhook and stores it in this manner. Is there a way I can get all the documents inside all the subcollections of a collection? For example, collectionA/records/subCollectionB/documents. I would like to get all the documents in subcollectionB for every "records"

Answer (score -2):

First of all u should update state after dom rendered the use useState or componentDidMount(). After that if u want to dont get error u should check the value of your state for example below

```
<div>
   {
   
   arrayOfObjects ? arrayOfObjects.map(obj=>(
     
      <div>

       obj.propertyName

     </div>
 
   )) 
   
   }
</div>
```